# How to display photo properties (ISO, Aperture, Exposure, Shutter Speed) in Drupal 7

Tags: media

everyone! I know that every image contains specific information about itself( ISO, Aperture, Exposure, Shutter Speed). The problem is how to display them in the article of Drupal 7? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [exif module](http://drupal.org/project/exif) should get you going.

> The Exif module allows you to display Exif metadata on image nodes.
>   Exif is a specification for the image file format used by digital
>   cameras.